# Making a BarChart showing many data points look better

Tags: plotting

I have a `BarChart` used to show traffic on a network interface. I have data for every 0.5s, upto 1 min, which gives a lot of points. Is there a way to make it look less chaotic and messy?

```
data = Import["/Users/matek/NetworkTest/without_use_in_and_out.csv", "Table"];

maxValues = 121;
labelValues = Range[0.0, maxValues*0.5, 0.5];
Show[
    BarChart[
        data[[1 ;; maxValues]],
        ChartLegends -> Placed[{"Outbound (TX)", "Inbound (RX)"}, {{0.5, 0}}],
        ChartLabels -> {labelValues, None},
        AxesLabel -> {"Duration [s]", "Bandwidth [byte/s]"}
    ],
     ImageSize -> 600,
     BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
     PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

The result

[image]

It's evident that the ticks and ChartLabels in the resulting BarChart look awful.

Comment: I think this issue has often been discussed before - searching previous questions will save everyone's time!

Comment: You might want to also try thinking about what you _want_ to convey with your chart before plotting it. Just because you have data streaming in at a high sample rate does not necessarily mean that you need to also present it at the same rate. For example with car traffic, it makes sense to use a unit of time that is _meaningful_ — for instance, "# of cars per minute" for the Los Angeles freeway in California or "# of cars per day" for a country road in England. In such cases, it is prudent to re-bin your data and then plot. If not, perhaps there are better representations than a barchart

Comment: @rm-rf, i am thankful for your concern, but this chart and representation is exactly what i need.

Comment: @JavaCake Ok, sounds good, and looks like cormullion's answer is what you were looking for :) I'll leave the comment up, as a general observation.

Comment: @rm-rf, it is exactly what i needed, the only problem i have left is the axes values in the `duration-axis` which has to be from `[0:60]` representing 1min measurement. I am not certain how this can be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With so much data, this is the best I could manage:

```
BarChart[RandomInteger[300, {120, 2}],
 ChartLegends -> Placed[{"Outbound (TX)", "Inbound (RX)"}, {{0.5, 0}}],
 ChartStyle ->
  {
   Directive[Orange, EdgeForm[None]],
   Directive[Blue, EdgeForm[None]]
   },
 Frame -> True,
 BarSpacing -> 2,
 FrameLabel -> {"duration (minutes:seconds)", "bandwidth"},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]],
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Automatic, None},
   {Table[{x, DateString[x, {"Minute", ":", "Second"}]}, {x, 0, 360, 
      30}] , None}},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: new version]

Comment: A world of difference. Is there a chance that i can change the axes numbers of `duration` to [0.5:60]?

Comment: @JavaCake The online reference has lots of information about `Ticks` and `FrameTicks`, and there are many existing questions here about them too. Have a play with the options.

Comment: lastly i have a question. When i have data points for `[1:120]`, why does the ticks value exceed 120?

Comment: @JavaCake Perhaps the BarSpacing option should be adjusted, eg to {1,1}?